# Handling fields of type List in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I'm using JasperReports and Java. In the report definition I want to access fields of objects which belong to a list of the main objects provided as report data source.

I have the following two Java classes:

```
public class NestedDto {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    // public getter methods
}
```

and

```
public class MainDto {
    private Long id;
    private List<NestedDto> nestedObjects;
    // public getter methods
}
```

The jasper report gets a list of MainDto objects as its data source using `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`.
In my report definition, I want to access the fields of the NestedDto objects.
My research shows that I can do that by importing the type NestedDto in Jaspersoft Studio, i.e. importing the file NestedDto.class. Afterwards I can cast the list's objects to NestedDto and then I can access the fields.

We have team colleagues who do not have access to the Java code. They need to rely on the interface documentation of our DTO classes.
Is there any way I can do that without the need of importing the Java classes?
Is it somehow possible to create a new `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` based on the field `nestedObjects`?

Comment: `Is there any way I can do that without the need of importing the Java classes?` - Do you need to access Java object's fields (with help of getters) without having this class at classpath?

Comment: Yes, exactely. We do not want to provide the .class files to the report designers.

Comment: One approach I have used to solve a similar problem, is to create a new type of flat object that contains all of the nested fields and parent object fields (and instantiate one per NestedDto), then add that as a JRBeanCollectionDataSource. This way, each row in the report corresponds to each nested object, but the parent object fields are still available too.

Comment: @ChristianMeier Another approach is to use datasource of another type, for example csv of json file. The template can be designed/created using such mock data

Comment: @AlexK / Dan Torrey: Thanks for your suggestions! These were exactely the kind of ideas I was looking for.